# Why does drawing bode plots on poles or zeros give different results?

Tags: transfer-function

Why does drawing bode plots on poles or zeros give different results?

For example I have a transfer function, I could write it for pole as $$\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)} \tag 1$$ or write it for zeros as $$1+\frac{s}{\omega_0} \tag 2$$ Here are the plots for pole and zeros:

[image]

($\omega_0=3$ in this plot)

How is that even possible? In my understanding it's just the same function but I orginized it in different styles. Why does it gives me different results?

Comment: Are you sure you're doing your math correctly? If you want to transform the function, you multiply by 1. This would give you the zero but also a double pole. Not sure what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

- Because your (2) is the reciprocal of your (1).
- Because a Bode plot should be a log-log scale (or amplitude in dB vs. log frequency -- which is the same thing, because the decibel is a logarithmic measure).

Incidentally, you're clearly plotting $s$ in the range $s \in [1, 10]$.  *This is incorrect*.  You should be plotting $s = j\omega$ for $\omega \in [1, 10]$ (note that I changed your notation so that your cutoff frequency is now $\omega_0$).

If you put the thing on a log-log plot, or a dB-log plot, then the fact that the one is the reciprocal of the other will become clear.

If you fix the fact that $s$ is real, then the results will start looking like real Bode plots.  If you run $s$ over a wider range -- i.e. $s = j\omega$ for $\omega \in [0.1, 100]$ then your plots will *really* start looking like Bode plots.